# Javascript document.location redirect to a wrong url

Tags: javascript, redirect

I use this following code to redirect if site was visited on mobile devices

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 978) {
document.location = "mobile.mysite.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

I tested it on many devices. Why does the site redirects to `www.mysite.com/mobile.mysite.com` instead of `mobile.mysite.com` only?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute URL path instead of a relative one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this thing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 978) {
document.location.href = "http://mobile.mysite.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify `'http://'` or just `'//'` at the beginning, otherwise the URL is treated as relative instead of absolute.

```
if (screen.width <= 978) {
    document.location.href = "//mobile.mysite.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `window.location.href` instead of `document.location` :)